# Recently Issue face in Input.date and Input.choice in AdaptiveCard While Integrating chatBot with Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

While using input.choice with confirmation message in adaptive card rest at that time dropdown of choice list is not showing up, we started facing this problem recently before it was working properly.
This was the code we were using at first when it was having proper behaviour

```
        TeamsAdaptiveCardRest adaptiveCardRest = new TeamsAdaptiveCardRest();

        List<TeamsItemsChoiceRest> choiceList =
                createTeamsItemChoiceRestList((MapUserMessageRest) chatUserResponse.getOptions());

        TeamsTextBlockRest textBlock = new TeamsTextBlockRest();
        textBlock.setText(chatUserResponse.getMessage());

        TeamsStaticItemListRest staticItemListRest = new TeamsStaticItemListRest();
        staticItemListRest.setChoices(choiceList);
        staticItemListRest.setPlaceholder("select");
        staticItemListRest.setId(String.valueOf(chatUserResponse.getChatBrainId()));

        TeamsToggleElementsRest enableConfirmationMessage = createToggleElements("confirmationToggle", true);
        TeamsToggleElementsRest enableActionButton = createToggleElements("actionButton", true);

        TeamsToggleActionRest toggleSelectAction = new TeamsToggleActionRest();
        toggleSelectAction
                .setTargetElements(Lists.newArrayList(enableConfirmationMessage, enableActionButton));

        TeamsContainerRest inputChoiceContainer = new TeamsContainerRest();
        inputChoiceContainer.setVisible(true);
        inputChoiceContainer.setItems(Lists.newArrayList(textBlock, staticItemListRest));
        inputChoiceContainer.setSelectAction(toggleSelectAction);
        adaptiveCardRest.addInBody(inputChoiceContainer);

        TeamsContainerRest confirmationMessageContainer = new TeamsContainerRest();
        confirmationMessageContainer.setItems(
                Lists.newArrayList(new TeamsTextBlockRest(chatUserResponse.getConfirmationMessage())));
        confirmationMessageContainer.setId("confirmationToggle");
        confirmationMessageContainer.setVisible(false);
        adaptiveCardRest.addInBody(confirmationMessageContainer);

        TeamsActionSubmitRest submitAction = new TeamsActionSubmitRest("Yes");
        TeamsToggleElementsRest disableConfirmationMessage =
                createToggleElements("confirmationToggle", false);
        TeamsToggleElementsRest disableActionButton = createToggleElements("actionButton", false);

        TeamsToggleActionRest toggleDisabledAction = new TeamsToggleActionRest();
        toggleDisabledAction
                .setTargetElements(Lists.newArrayList(disableConfirmationMessage, disableActionButton));
        toggleDisabledAction.setTitle("Cancel");

        TeamsActionSetRest actionButtionSetRest = new TeamsActionSetRest();
        actionButtionSetRest.setVisible(false);
        actionButtionSetRest.setId("actionButton");
        actionButtionSetRest.setActions(Lists.newArrayList(submitAction, toggleDisabledAction));
        adaptiveCardRest.addInBody(actionButtionSetRest);
        return adaptiveCardRest;

Json for the above code:


{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.5",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "id": null,
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Input.choice",
          "wrap": true
        },
        {
          "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
          "choices": [
            {
              "title": "a",
              "value": "aa",
              "id": "aa"
            }
          ],
          "id": "39",
          "value": null,
          "placeholder": "select"
        }
      ],
      "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
        "title": null,
        "id": null,
        "targetElements": [
          {
            "elementId": "confirmationToggle",
            "visible": true,
            "isVisible": true
          },
          {
            "elementId": "actionButton",
            "visible": true,
            "isVisible": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "visible": true,
      "isVisible": true
    },
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "id": "confirmationToggle",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Are you sure?",
          "wrap": true
        }
      ],
      "selectAction": null,
      "visible": false,
      "isVisible": false
    },
    {
      "type": "ActionSet",
      "actions": [
        {
          "type": "Action.Submit",
          "title": "Yes",
          "associatedInputs": "auto",
          "data": null
        },
        {
          "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
          "title": "Cancel",
          "id": null,
          "targetElements": [
            {
              "elementId": "confirmationToggle",
              "visible": false,
              "isVisible": false
            },
            {
              "elementId": "actionButton",
              "visible": false,
              "isVisible": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "id": "actionButton",
      "visible": false,
      "isVisible": false
    }
  ],
  "selectAction": null,
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
}
```

We are facing same issue in input.date with confirmation message in that dropdown of datepicker doesn't show up

Due to the change in behaviour the dropdown of input.choice and input.date Doesn't show with confirmation message so It was working properly before but recently behaviour changed, So want to know the reason behind the change in behaviour.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boDby.png)

Comment: Could you please share screenshots of it and also please share if you are referring to any sample?

Comment: Attach screenshot shows our sample adaptive card of input.choice which is working properly on adaptive card.io but not during implementation ( I had provide json for same)

Comment: We checked this and had the following repro - 

Desktop & Web : Nothing is shown when I click on dropdown - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CoX7.png

Android - Dropdown values are shown but Yes/Cancel buttons are not shown - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3cdB.jpg , https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzQ9O.jpg

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are also facing the same issue, meanwhile we are checking this with the team.

Comment: Yes I'm facing the same issue with input.choice and input.date

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same and team is looking into it. We will keep you posted on the bug fix.

Comment: Yes please let me know after this bug fix.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT can I know that this bug is fixed or not??? Still I'm facing this issue pls help me out.